# PowerBI Line Chart with X-Y lines that intersect with primary line chart?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Given a line chart.
How can I draw additional lines that intersect with the primary line chart?

[image]

Comment: Your best option is probably to use a Python or R visual for that.

Comment: I would use Deneb for this.